# Applying pandas bar style to a dataframe using values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I have df1 and df2. I want to show bars in cells of df1 using values from df2. I was able to apply other forms of styling using below code, but with bars you cannot use this method.

```
def color_cells(s):
    if s > 90:
        return 'color:{0}; font-weight:bold'.format('green')
    elif s>80:
        return 'background-color: light yellow;color:{0}; font-weight:regular'.format('dark yellow')
    else:
        return 'color:{0}; font-weight:bold'.format('red')

df1.style.apply(lambda x: df2.applymap(color_cells), axis=None)
```

My code for getting bars in df2 is

```
df2.style.bar(color=['#d65f5f', '#5fba7d'])
```

How do I apply above code to df1? Index and column names are same.

Adding sample dataframe:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 10))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 10)*100)
```

Comment: Could you please add some sample data for the two dataframes?

Comment: Added the sample df1 and df2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code that does that:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 10))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(15, 10)*100)

pct = (df2 - df2.min()) / (df2.max() - df2.min() )*100

def make_bar_style(x):
    return f"background: linear-gradient(90deg,#5fba7d {x}%, transparent {x}%); width: 10em"    
pct.applymap(make_bar_style).shape

df1.style.apply(lambda x: pct.applymap(make_bar_style), axis=None)
```

The result is:

[image]

To demonstrate the fact that bar sizes are driven by df2, consider the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.mgrid[0:15, 0:10][0])
```

The result is then:

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm!